# How do I stop a Bootstrap x-editable from updating an edited field when ajax call fails?

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

How do I stop a Bootstrap x-editable from updating an edited field when ajax call fails?

I am passing a function as the url.

```
$('.order-price').editable({
    type: "text",
    title: "Order Price",
    url: function (params) {
        var orderID = $(this).data("order-id");
        var data = "OrderID=" + orderID + "&Price=" + params.value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/Trades/SetOrderPrice',
            data: data,
            async: false,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                return false;
                // Do I return something here instead of false?

            }

        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html shows some methods like  disable() can't you use them?

Comment: The 'disabled()' method is for disabling the editing functionality of the field...this does not address the question.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options, either throw exception in the callback and x-editable will catch it itself or you can use the "success" event and return an empty string in the success function and you're set

Comment: This is *incredibly* useful to me!!!! Just `return "";` and it works perfectly!!!

Comment: Returning an empty string from the success callback is not an acceptable option. From the xEditable documentation: "If (success callback) returns string - means error occurred and string is shown as error message." - so you'll end up with a field in error but no error msg.

Comment: Which appears to be OK if you're using 'inline' fields. But 'popup' fields will suffer with this technique.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use build-in ajax call that will automatically keep old value in case of error:

```
$('.order-price').editable({
  type: "text",
  title: "Order Price",
  url: '/Trades/SetOrderPrice', 
  params: function (params) {
    return {
      orderID: $(this).data("order-id"),
      value: params.value        
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to save the old value even if the ajax succeed?

Answer (score 1):

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    var oldValueObj = $(this).editable('getValue'); //get old value obj

    for(var key in oldValueObj) {
        var value = oldValueObj[key]; //get old value in loop if we don't know key

        return {newValue: value}; //set old value and stop x-editable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making ajax request from url, one possible solution is to invoke the editable error method, and you can keep track of that method during initialization.

```
url: function(params) {
            var url = '/xxx/yyy/dosomething';

            var success = $(this).data('editable').options.success;
            var error = $(this).data('editable').options.error;

            // call your ajax request and invoke success

             $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: url,
                data: data
                async: false,
                error: function(x,y,z) {
                  error();
                },
                success: function(x,y,z) {
                  success();
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a Deffered object's promise at the end of your function for the 'url' option. Returning this tells x-editable to not change the value in the client side data until resolve is run on that Deferred object. If reject() ends up being run then the old value remains.

```
url: function (params) {

    /***ADD DEFERRED***/
    var d = new $.Deferred()
    var orderID = $(this).data("order-id");
    var data = "OrderID=" + orderID + "&Price=" + params.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Trades/SetOrderPrice',
        data: data,
        async: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           /***RESOLVE THE DEFERRED OBJECT***/
           d.resolve(); 
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            /***REJECT IF ERROR OCCURRED***/
            d.reject(thrownError);
            //d.reject(''); //You could also return just an empty string, but must return a string


        }

    })

    /*** RETURN A PROMISE ***/
    return d.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code ,it worked for me successfully

$(".editable-open").editableContainer("hide");